# C++: Why my recursion trims my array rather than perform the intended purpose that it should recursively fill an array with values?

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

While I was doing the C++ test, I had a problem asking me to recursively fill in an array with the values falling in the range in which the lowest value and highest value are randomly generated. Here is my code of the recursive function:

```
int * recursivelyFillTheArray(int &arrLength, int &minValue, int &maxValue, int *arrToFill){
    if (arrLength == 0) {
        return arrToFill;
    } else {
        arrToFill[arrLength - 1] = rand() % (abs(minValue) + maxValue) - abs(minValue);
        arrLength -= 1;
        return recursivelyFillTheArray(arrLength, minValue, maxValue, arrToFill);
    }
}
```

However, the returned output only shows an array of length of 2 and the second value is always a 0. like [-1,0], [4,0].

I then added a printArray() function inside of this recursivelyFillTheArray(), and surprisingly find out the function actually trims my array in the loop rather than fill in the array with the value. Like:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0]
[0, 0]
[-8, 0]
```

I cannot figure out why. And here is the fully compiled code with the debug output.

https://ideone.com/quszeM

Please if you could help me see the reason and how to fix it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: In addition to the answers; remember that you fill in the random value at the top (rightmost) position, then you print out the content of the array up to, but not including the position you just assigned the random value to.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: When you iterating over array elements you increment/decrement the index not the size. So in your example you are using the size as an index and length at the same time. Also there's no need to return `int*` as long as you pass the array to be filled.

Comment: @nos Yes! After realizing the arrayLen changes in printArray(), I see the problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you're modifying `arrLength` - don't pass by reference unnecessarily.
You're also filling the array "backwards", with decreasing indices, but printing it "forwards", so you stop printing immediately before the value you just generated.
(As a bonus, printing those array elements is undefined since you never initialized the array. If you initialize it with 999, you'll see a whole lot of 999s.)

Perhaps this gets clearer if you replace the function call in `main` with the equivalent loop;

```
while (arrLength > 0) {
    arrToFill[arrLength - 1] = rand() % (abs(minValue) + maxValue) - abs(minValue);
    arrLength -= 1;
    printArray(theArray, arrLength); 
}
```

There doesn't seem to be any point in returning the `arrToFill` parameter, so something like this perhaps:

```
void recursivelyFillTheArray(int arrLength, int minValue, int maxValue, int *arrToFill){
    if (arrLength > 0) {
        arrToFill[arrLength - 1] = rand() % (abs(minValue) + maxValue) - abs(minValue);
        recursivelyFillTheArray(arrLength - 1, minValue, maxValue, arrToFill);
    }
}
```

or if you want a "forward fill",

```
void recursivelyFillTheArray(int arrLength, int minValue, int maxValue, int *arrToFill){
    if (arrLength > 0) {
        arrToFill[0] = rand() % (abs(minValue) + maxValue) - abs(minValue);
        recursivelyFillTheArray(arrLength - 1, minValue, maxValue, arrToFill + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Yes that's it. Also mention to the OP the return value as you did here. The OP's return value is redundant,

Comment: @Raindrop7 Thanks! The return type was actually required in the test, so I just carried it here :D

Comment: Thanks for your answer molbdnilo I now get it! The main problem is indeed I modified my arrayLen with call by reference, but initially I thought my array was trimmed, and now I realized as you said, it is because the arrayLen is modified "globally" so when printing out the array, the arrayLen will only be 0, then the function will just print out the part of the array. So the array is actually not trimmed, but the array print-out. And I also appreciate your other hints. I just learned call by reference in my last class, so in test I had to use it amap. Thanks again! I fixed it now :)